# grafana inter-panel communication

Tags: javascript, angularjs, grafana

I have started learning about Grafana custom panels & apps, but have been unable to find any information on how to control or pass information between custom panels in the same App. In a normal Angular / React application you would use state management (NGRX / Redux) to achieve this, but how would I do this with Grafana?

For example Panel A contains:

- table of data with filters from data source

Panel B contains:

- some configurable parameters
- the results of calculations using the filtered data from Panel A, and the selected parameters in Panel B

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you can use data from Panel A as a datasource for Panel B:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/features/datasources/

> Dashboard - Select this to use a result set from another panel in the same dashboard